# How can I completely hide an irrelevant directory of type declarations from TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to improve my `tsc` build times and editor responsiveness by reducing the number of source files that TypeScript pulls in. I'm seeing lots of `.d.ts` files in `node_modules` that are being pulled in via transitive dependencies, and I'd like a way to exclude them from consideration during compilation.

To make this more concrete: I'm using [PgTyped](https://github.com/adelsz/pgtyped) to generate TypeScript type declarations for my SQL queries. To use it, I need to install two dependencies:

```
npm install @pgtyped/query @pgtyped/cli
```

The `@pgtyped/query` package depends on [`antlr4ts`](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4ts), which [ships with](https://yarnpkg.com/package/antlr4ts?files) many bundled `.d.ts` files of its own. These get pulled into my `node_modules` directory:

```
$ ls node_modules/antlr4ts/**/*.d.ts | wc -l
179
```

Some of these types *do* get pulled in via `node_modules/@pgtyped/query/lib/index.d.ts`. I can see this by using `tsc --listFiles`:

```
$ tsc --noEmit --listFiles | grep antlr4ts
/myrepo/ts/node_modules/antlr4ts/atn/ATNStateType.d.ts
/myrepo/ts/node_modules/antlr4ts/misc/Stubs.d.ts
/myrepo/ts/node_modules/antlr4ts/misc/IntegerList.d.ts
/myrepo/ts/node_modules/antlr4ts/misc/Interval.d.ts
...
```

So far as I can tell (famous last words!) these are all irrelevant to the public API of PgTyped. If I just replaced them with `any`, there would be no observable difference to my app and there would be ~100 fewer files that `tsc` would need to load.

I've tried a few techniques suggested on the TypeScript Wiki's [Performance Page](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance#configuring-tsconfigjson-or-jsconfigjson), namely including `**/node_modules` in my `exclude`:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [ "dom", "DOM.Iterable", "es2019" ],
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    // ... many other settings ...
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./cypress",
    "**/node_modules",
    "**/.*/"
  ]
}
```

I've set `skipLibCheck` and also tried creating a declaration file to stub out `antlr4ts`:

```
// declarations/antlr4ts.d.ts
declare module 'antlr4ts';
```

This file shows up in the output of `tsc --listFiles`, but only *after* all 110 of the `antlr4ts` declarations files.

Is it possible to prevent TypeScript from seeing any of these `.d.ts` files? Ideally I'd like to have it give all of these `antlr4ts` modules an `any` type.

Comment: man, why do you want exclude things, which are necessary for libs?!

Comment: @BartłomiejStasiak the answer is clearly explained in the 1st sentence the OPs question

Comment: Surely `@pgtyped/cli` should be installed as a dev dependency only?

Comment: @Bergi that's true, however the issue here is a dependency of `@pgtyped/query`, not `@pgtyped/cli`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in tsconfig:

```
"paths": {
    "antlr4ts" : ["NOT_EXISTS"] 
}
```

or perhaps point it to your declarations file

```
"paths": {
    "antlr4ts" : ["declarations/antlr4ts.d.ts"] 
}
```

Sidenote - I'm not sure if it will save a significant amount of build time, even if it works

Comment: Another thing to do would be to split type checking and building into two processes. You could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently with -k to spin up on the one hand 'tsc --no-emit' for typechecking and on the other something like swc  https://swc.rs/blog/swc-1#typescript-support or babel to transpile the code from TS to JS without type-checking it

Comment: `paths` was the key, thanks @anton-mihaylov! To get this to work, I had to point at declarations files that _did_ exist. And I had to tweak the declarations for `@pgtyped/query` a bit to reduce what it imported. But it did work! See https://gist.github.com/danvk/8be29b26a814e677245aec52f0788d4c for full details.

Comment: Nice! Did you notice any effect on the build or dev transpilation speed?

Comment: not measurably (I timed five before/after runs of `tsc --noEmit --incremental false` and saw no significant change). But I'm mostly excited to have a technique for controlling which files get included. Next step for me is to prune some of the larger, more complex dependencies from my project.

Comment: Yeah, it is nice to know you can easily redeclare your types. Just to note - doing --incremental doesn't make sense for performance runs since it will use the existing cache

Comment: Yes, but that's what the `false` is for :)

Comment: Oh right,  missed that :)

Answer (score 3):

To improve your **editor responsiveness**, you can try adding `watchOptions` with `excludeDirectories` to your *tsconfig* file ([doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#watch-excludeDirectories)). This way, you can tell your editor should not to search inside *node_modules*.
From [Typescript webpage](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#Watch_and_Build_Modes_6250):

> TypeScript 3.8 introduces a new watchOptions field which allows users to tell the compiler/language service which watching strategies should be used to keep track of files and directories.

About the **build time**, typescript does not compile the files inside your *node_modules*, it only looks for type declaration files (d.ts). This should be quick (a few seconds) but it doesn't seem to be a solution to ignoring those files at the moment. One thing you can do to reduce **build time** is to use [Typescript's **incremental mode**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#incremental) when compiling. This will save compiler info into your project and speed up the following compilations.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `excludeDirectories`. I'll give that a shot! I do have `skipLibCheck` set, but my concern is that, presumably, `tsc` and `tsserver` still have to load all the type declarations under `node_modules` into memory in case you reference them. For my project that's a lot of code: ~20MB of `.d.ts` files under `node_modules` vs. only ~7MB of my own code (including some JSON files I import).